# How to use a symbol above a word without a larger linespacing?

Tags: symbols, line-spacing, accents, exam

Because of the "1" symbol above "test", the space between the first two lines is bigger than between the last two lines. I don't want a bigger interline spacing! How do I solve this?[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,addpoints,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{accents}       

\newtcolorbox{blackbox}[1][]{}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\pointsaboveword}[2][2]{%
$\accentset{\color{blue}#1}{\textnormal{\textbf{#2}}}$}

\begin{questions}

\begin{blackbox}
\question[1]
Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit is een  \pointsaboveword[1]{test}. Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit is een test.Dit is een test.
\end{blackbox}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\smash` macro hides the true height and depth of its argument from TeX. You could write

```
\smash{\pointsaboveword[1]{test}}
```

to "trick" TeX into not noticing that the combined word has extra height. As a result, TeX won't increase the line spacing.

Observe that if the text is single-spaced and the word immediately above the raised `1` (or `2`, ...) symbol has a letter with a descender (e.g., "g" or "y"), the symbols will collide. Not good. Instead of going the `\smash` route, you may consider increasing the line spacing a bit; 15% is probably enough. To do this, load the `setspace` package and set `\setstretch{1.15}`. To confine the scope of this command to just the `blackbox` environment, you could insert the following commands in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox,setspace}
\AtBeginEnvironment{blackbox}{\setstretch{1.15}}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure this is a good idea, as the example I present should show:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,addpoints,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{blackbox}[1][]{}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\pointsaboveword}[2][2]{%
  \strut
  \smash{%
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{-1000}% get the lines in the tabular as tight as possible
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
    \tiny #1\\\bfseries #2
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
}

\begin{questions}

\begin{blackbox}
\question[1]
Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit 
is een \pointsaboveword[1]{test}. Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit 
is een test. Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit is een test.Dit is een 
test.
\end{blackbox}

\begin{blackbox}
\question[1]
Dit is egn test. Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit 
is een \pointsaboveword[1]{test}. Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit 
is een test. Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit is een test.Dit is een 
test.
\end{blackbox}

\begin{blackbox}
\question[1]
Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit 
is een \pointsaboveword[1]{tefst}. Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit 
is een test. Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit is een test. Dit is een test.Dit is een 
test.
\end{blackbox}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]